# How to set images to a DataGridViewImage column?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a datagridview control called datagridview1.
it has a few columns present in it.
Now, I wanted to add an image column to the datagridview, so I did the following.

```
DataGridViewImageColumn d1 = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
datagridview1.Columns.Add(d1);
```

Then I wanted to display images on the image column based on the values present in the other columns.
So, here is a sample of what I did.

```
for(int i = 0;i<numberofrowsingrid;i++)
{
   if(/*checking if value present in other columns satisy conditions*/)
   {
       datagridview1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value = Image.FromFile("path of the image");
   }
}
```

The image columns index is 9.
But doing this does not change the image present in the cells.
I get a x mark on the cell.
Kindly help.

Comment: What type (jpg or bmp or ico) of image do you set?

Comment: I use an icon with .ico extension. I tried with png as well, but its not working

Comment: Try setting the ValuesAreIcon property to true for the DataGridViewImageColumn

Comment: Try putting this code in the CellFormatting   

  ` void myDGV_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!myDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
            {
                if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
                {
                    e.Value = Image.FromFile(@"../../Resources\Image1.jpg");
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: Exact same code work for me. May be your `if(/*checking if value present in other columns satisfy conditions*/) return false for all rows?`

Comment: @Fabio The condition does not return false for all rows. I placed a breakpoint inside to check during execution. Maybe I will try the code which Junaith has given.